# Firebase swift observers printing duplicate data and also in Tableview cells in UI

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase observer, as shown below each time i print or implemented it in my UI i get duplicate data in tableView cell. Can someone please advise how to remove the duplicate data.
I am populating my UI from visiblePosts.

```
  var users = [String:Any]()
  var posts = [String:Any]()
  var usersposts = [String:Any]()
  var currentUserKey:String!
  var visiblePosts = [String:Any]()

  func getUserData(){
    DataService.ds.REF_USERS.observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in 
      let key = snapshot.key
      let data = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
      self.users[key] = data
    })
  }

  func getPostsData(){
    DataService.ds.REF_POST.observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in 
      let key = snapshot.key
      let data = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
      self.posts[key] = data
      self.refreshPosts()
    })
 }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      self.currentUserKey = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)! 
      self.getUserData()
      self.getPostsData()
      self.getUsersPostsData()

      // data will be refreshed anytime a child is added
 }

 func refreshPosts(){
      self.visiblePosts = [:]
      let validUsers = [String]() // this will hold the valid keys to get posts
      validUsers.append(self.currentUserKey)

      // filter the current user data to get the friends
      let currentUserData = users[self.currentUserKey] 

      // get friends keys
      let friendsData = currentUserData["friends"] as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
      for key in friendsData.keys {
         // add friends posts to the validposts data
         validUsers.append(key)
      }
      // get current users posts:
      for (key,value) in self.posts {
         let postData = value as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
         let whoposted = postData["whoposted"] as? String ?? ""
         if validUsers.contains(whoposted){
             self.visiblePosts[key] = postData
         }
      }
      // access the self.validposts data in your UI however you have it setup
      // The child added queries above will continue to fire off and refresh 
      // your data when new posts are added.
      // I am still not clear what the usersposts data is for so it is omitted here.
     }
```

Comment: A couple of things. Your question states you have a Firebase query, but there are no queries in the code, just observes. Also, what data is duplicated? It's not outlined in the question.

Comment: @Jay So sorry for the missup. I meant observer not query. The data I appended to the array visiblePosts. It is from this array i am populating my tableview cell. The data in my table View cell is duplicated. I have also edited the title

Comment: It looks to me that by adding a .childAdded observer, which will fire once for each node  and then again when any new nodes are added, you are calling refreshPosts over and over - once for every child in the node. So there's quite a bit of redundancy on the refreshPosts() function which is where the duplication is coming from.